# How to design a ReactJS component that listens to a WebSocket and interacts with CSS animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

A ReactJS component needs to listen for events emitted by a WebSocket.

For each inbound event the component should render a DOM node.

It should then wait for the CSS animation associated with the DOM node to complete, and then remove the DOM node.

This is a sketch of my intended implementation.

Does this approach look workable?

The `setTimeout` feels horrible.

```
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent {
 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.webSocket.on('myEvent', componentDidReceiveEvent)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.webSocket.off('myEvent', componentDidReceiveEvent)  
  }

  // is this method style valid syntax?
  componentDidReceiveEvent = limit((evt) => {
    this.state.setState((prev, props) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        inboundEvents: [...prev.events, evt]
      };
      setTimeout(function() {
        // use Array API to remove evt from the 
        // inboundEvents array on this.state
      }, DURATION_OF_CSS_ANIMATION);
    });
  })

  render() {
    return (<div>
      {this.state.events.map(e => <MyNode key={evt.id} />)}
    </div>);
  }
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  id: React.PropTypes.string,
  webSocket: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
    React.PropTypes.bool,
    React.PropTypes.object,
  ]),
};
```

Comment: I assume you're using babel `transform-class-properties`. If you are, then yes the method is valid syntax.

Comment: missing some curly braces in your render method there

Comment: I don't see where you have initialized your state in constructor though.

Comment: @rossipedia his return state will actually work without `()`, they're not required, but definitely help readability.

Comment: curly braces, not parens ;) `<div>{this.state.map()}</div>` instead of `<div>this.state.map()</div>` (looks like it's fixed)

Comment: @rossipedia my mistake! You are correct sir, I didn't even notice that... /slapself

Comment: Thank you for the brace correction!

Comment: @KyleRichardson What do you expect to see in the ctor? `this.state = initialValue`?

Comment: @BenAston Yes. `this.state.events.map` will result in `Cannot read property map of undefined` on your initial render if you don't at least do `this.state = { events: null }` as an initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `setTimeout` feels hacky (a view I tend to agree with), you could use the [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) event instead.

> The transitionend event is fired when a CSS transition has completed. In the case where a transition is removed before completion, such as if the transition-property is removed or display is set to "none", then the event will not be generated.

Aside from that I don't really see anything wrong with your approach

Comment: I up voted this answer, but another thing you might want to look into is [High-level API: ReactCSSTransitionGroup](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#high-level-api-reactcsstransitiongroup)

Comment: Great suggestion! I've used CSSTransitionGroup several times with great results

Comment: @rossipedia I am concerned that the correct DOM nodes are removed. Presumably the inclusion of the `key` will ensure this is OK?

Comment: As long as the value passed to key is unique and won't be reused across child elements, then yes: react will remove the correct DOM elements

Answer (score 1):

Use [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)

You can add a listener to the websocket in the app launcher (typically App.js / index.js or something similar).  When data comes in the websocket, just call the [Flux Action](https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples/flux-concepts#flow-of-data) that triggers a store update.  The React component can have a store listener and know when to update component state & re-render.

Comment: OK, so handle events from the WebSocket in one location and dispatch events to the store from there. ... and then use redux-connect to ensure that component state is connected to the store and have the component render i the same way - just with local state changes being controlled by store changes? Is there not a downside that this spreads concerns outside of the component?

Comment: @BenAston something like that - yes.  I've used a pure Flux implementation (not redux) with the [Flux utils store](https://github.com/cagedtornado/centralconfig-ui/blob/master/js/stores/ConfigStore.js#L6) and [store listeners](https://github.com/cagedtornado/centralconfig-ui/blob/master/js/components/MainApp.react.js#L51-L52) -- but your architecture sounds like it should work as well.